# select2 'change' event doesn't trigger for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have Select2 Javascript widget on my page.

```js
$('#order_address_select').select2({
  placeholder: "Select adress",
  ajax: {
    url: '<?=Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)?>/order/getplacemarklist',
    dataType: 'json',
  },
  tags: true,
});
```

When I'm typing some text, and if it is not found in database and not loaded through ajax, I can anyway choose it, cause attribute `tags` is setted to `true`. Then I have following code

```js
 $('#order_address_select').change(function () {
   alert($("#order_address_select option[data-select2-tag='true']").val());
 });
```

The problem is when I'm typing text, and selecting it as a tag, event doesnt trigger for the first time. But when I'm typing text again, and selecting it, code alerts value of previously selected option. For example: I'm typing "aaa", selecting it, nothing happens, then I'm typing "bbb", selecting it, and got alert with "aaa"

Answer (score 6):

So, if anyone is interested, I found solution on select2 github repository, you just need to add an empty `<option></option>` to your `<select>`. And then it will work fine

Comment: Amazing! this has solved my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside my change handler I get the selected option as

```
var data = $(this).select2("data")[0];
```

Like this:

```
$selectXXXXX.on('change', function (e) {
        var data = $(this).select2("data")[0];
        var cfg = configuraciones[data.id];
        app.usersFocusChange(data.id, cfg); 
});
```

[Ref: select2 dox](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections)

Comment: This example is also triggers only with the second selection. Btw it works fine with values that are loaded from database

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it by manipulating html :

```js
$('#yourselect2').append("<option selected value='your_val'>your_text</option>");
```